# localisation of state space equations for synchronous machine

Tags: model, initialization, modelica

In modelica, for solving the der(**X**)=**AX**+**Bu** which describes state space equations of a synchronous machine, i am technically forced to give initial value for vector **u** (this value is obtained by the steady state equations of machine). After initialization, the vector **u** will change. How is it possible to implement it in Modelica?
**u** is the vector of voltage, **X** vector of flux, **A** vector of inductance.

Answer (score 1):

Those equations are normally non-obvious in the Modelica model.

I would recommend to just linearize the model which will give you A,B (and if you have outputs also C,D)-matrices.

Note that linearization is in general slightly different compared to what you write, as it is

```
 der(X)=A*(X-X0)+B*(U-U0);
```

when linearizing at X0, U0 and assuming X0, U0 is steady-state. If X0 isn't a steady-state point you will get:

```
 der(X)-X0_der=A*(X-X0)+B*(U-U0);
```

where X0_der is the derivative at X0. And adding explicit time-dependency will make it even messier.

Answer (score 1):

Are you sure, that you want to change `u` after initialization? What effect should that have on the model if the input value changes at time 0 before the simulation has started? Usually you initialize states, not inputs.

However, the Modelica Standard Library features a block for state space models (`Modelica.Blocks.Continuous.StateSpace`). You can use that one directly, or use its as inspiration to build your own model (due to the more complex initialization, which you are apparently dealing with).

Your model could look as follows:

```
model MyStateSpace

  parameter Real A[:, nx]=[1, 0; 0, 1] "System matrix";
  parameter Real B[nx, :]=[1; 1] "Input matrix";
  parameter Real C[:, nx]=[1, 1] "Output matrix";
  parameter Real D[ny, nu]=zeros(size(C, 1), size(B, 2)) "Feedthrough matrix";

  Real u[nu] "Input vector";
  Real x[size(A, 1)] "State vector";
  output Real y[size(C, 1)] "Output vector";

protected 
  final parameter Integer nx = size(A, 1) "number of states";
  final parameter Integer ny = size(C, 1) "number of outputs";
  final parameter Integer nu = size(B, 2) "number of inputs";

initial equation 

  x = {1, 0};

  /* put your equations for initialization here */

equation 

  u = if time > 0.1 then { sin(time) } else { 7 };

  der(x) = A*x + B*u;
  y = C*x + D*u;

end MyStateSpace;
```

In the `initial equation` section you can put your equations for initialization. In this example I initialized `x`, not `u`. To show how `u` could change its value after a certain time, I included an exemplary equation.

Comment: in synchronous machine model, we have to start from steady state, the state variables are flux,  I have used der(flux)=0 in initial equation to find the steady state initialization. we have two variable Efss as field voltage used to find the steady state values and Ef the field voltage.

Comment: I still don't get the actual question. Could you post the synchronous machine model? And why don't you just use the one provided in the MSL?